# LU Factorization. Finding L and A given y, b and U

Tags: linear-algebra, lu-decomposition

In a question I am given this information:

$$ U = 
\begin {bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 3\\
\end {bmatrix}
 $$

$$L \mathbf y = \begin {bmatrix}
3\\
13\\
4\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$

$$\mathbf y = \begin {bmatrix}
2\\
2\\
3\\
\end {bmatrix}
$$

The question asks to solve the the solution $ A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$. I got the values :
$\mathbf x = \begin {bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1\\ \end {bmatrix}$.

I need to find a basis for the $col(A)$ and the $row(A)$.

To find the basis for the row space I can simply use the rows of the U matrix, however, to find the column space I need A. Is there a way to find A or am I missing some theory that allows me to find the column space with the information I am given.

**Question is from UofT MAT223 December 2017 Final Exam (cite given for anti -plagarism purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, let's think.  If the matrix has an LU factorization, then it is of full rank.  So, the column space of $ A $ is ...

Comment: The column space of A would be the 3 standard basis?

Comment: No, that would a basis for the column space.  The column space is a space.  Not a set of vectors.